# import statements fail on react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React, and I have a php project set up like this:

In the head of index.php I load:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/react.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/react-dom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/browser.min.js"></script>
```

and at the bottom:

```
<script type="text/babel" src="jsx/index.jsx"></script>
<script> 
        window.onload=function(){ 
         site.init();
         }</script>
</script>
```

I'm not doing any transpiling. Everything runs fine on Apache+Firefox.

Then I wanted to add some transitions, like images fading in and out when clicking a button instead of just switching. So I:

1- downloaded react transition from here: https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group

2- added the content of its src folder to js, which now looks like this:

```
js/
../<some vanilla.js files>
../libs/
../libs/react.js
../libs/react-dom.js
../libs/browser.min.js
../libs/react-transition-group/
......./react-transition-group/index.js
......./react-transition-group/CSSTransitionGroup.js
......./react-transition-group/CSSTransitionGroup.js
......./react-transition-group/TransitionGroup.js
```

3- loaded index.js like this:

Now, on Chrome, I get this error when I run the site:

```
index.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

On Firefox:

```
SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module  index.js:1
```

Any idea about what am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: The browser doesn't know anything about import, require(), etc. suggested reading: http://blog.andrewray.me/webpack-when-to-use-and-why/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to use import, you should not use the babel polyfill, but transpile the code with babel. Therefore, it's highly encouraged to use webpack in your react project with a babel plugin.

This blog might help you further with setting up a react/webpack/babel project: https://scotch.io/tutorials/setup-a-react-environment-using-webpack-and-babel

Comment: @Andy Ray, @dejakob Thanks for the links. Actually I haven't used `import` anywhere around, neither needed any kind of transpiling to get the react site running ok (before adding transitions); `import` is used in the very first line of the react transition library's index.js, which I expected to run out of the box.
Does this mean that I have no other option than adding a intermediate step for transpiling while developing? As in modify code->transpile->check in browser vs modify code->check in browser?

Comment: In most front end projects some kind of transpiling is used to support ES6 and other features. With a correct watch setup and sourcemaps, it's not such a hassle IMO.

Answer (score 0):

As Andy Ray stated here http://blog.andrewray.me/webpack-when-to-use-and-why, it looks like I was doing things the old way; the wheel has been reinvented and the php-webpacker-of-sorts I use seems to start to lag behind.

It seems that I was unfortunately lucky to use a set of libraries that posed no conflict when imported just as `<script src=library.js>`, and react-transition dispelled that illusion. Following dejakob advice, I've integrated transpiling in the process and, at least for the moment, things seem to work seamlessly again.

Thanks